# How to determine if someone is connected to the internet in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I wrote a simple if statement to check first is someone was connected to the internet using the NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() method:

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    //EXECUTE
}
else
{
    //DISPLAY MESSAGE TO CONNECT TO INTERNET
}
```

Everytime I run it though it keeps returning true. I've actually disconnected it from the internet, wifi, and even tried airplane mode with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MrLacey has seen this in the emulator and when debugging - http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2010/12/wp7dev-gotchas-when-detecting-network.html

> 1. If you call this method in code running in the emulator it will always
>      return true.
> 2. If you call this method in code running on a tethered device (as you
>      may have connected when debugging on a
>      real device) it will always return
>      true.

Comment: wow this is good to know. Thanks you saved me a ton headaches.

Comment: A good approach is to wrap the call in your own code / interface so you can stub it out for testing.

Comment: There are quite a few gotchyas in this area at the moment. Be aware of this thread when relying on network status apis. http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/66651.aspx